# How does aircraft leasing work?

Tags: airplane, rental

I've noticed on websites where you can buy and sell aircraft, such as controller.com and trade-a-plane.com, there are often aircraft that are available for lease. For example, there is a 1997 Bonanza available for $4,000 a month on controller.com. I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about how aircraft leasing works. Is it similar to leasing a car? What is generally the minimum amount of time you can lease for? Is the person leasing the aircraft responsible for all maintenance costs, etc. If anyone knows anything about how this works, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: This question is more of a financial nature than an aviation question. As such it should probably be posted at https://money.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

Leasing airplanes is a popular way of exploiting certain quirks of the tax laws to (slightly) reduce the costs of owning and operating an airplane. The basic idea is similar to that of leasing a car but the details are more complex, in that the business entity that leases out the airplane experiences certain tax benefits in the transaction.

Those details get worked out between the parties in a process in which their lawyers have copies of the tax code in their laps while they decide exactly who pays for maintenance, etc.

Deals like this only make sense if you are very wealthy and have smart financial advisors working for you. So for example when Bill Hewlett and Dave Packard were both still alive and involved with HP's business, it was said that each personally owned a Rockwell Sabreliner which they leased to HP. HP could then deduct the lease cost as a business expense but because the jets did not show on HP's books as capital assets, HP could not depreciate their value annually. Bill and Dave showed the lease payments as income but got the benefit of the depreciation and could reserve the use of either jet for their own use at will. The net result was sufficiently beneficial to both H & P and to HP that they managed their two-jet fleet in that way.

Isn't capitalism grand?